# How to make options for popup window..eg size

Tags: javascript

I have the following function to make a popup window.

```
function makewindows(html){
child1 = window.open ("about:blank");
child1.document.write(html);
child1.document.close(); 
}
```

It works fine, but it opens a new tab in firefox. I would like to know how to make it an actual popup, with a smaller size and such, separate from the actual window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.open("example.html", "windowName",
            "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
```

See the [MSDN window.open documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx) or the [Mozilla window.open documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.open) for more details.